# how to intercept standard output of a dotnetcore process for interactive linux commands

Tags: .net-core

I need to run some interactive commands in dotnet core and interact with the output received. The problem I am encountering is that it doesn't trigger the read error or output events. Here is the example code I am using :

```
command_process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "/bin/bash",
        Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        WorkingDirectory = working_directory,
    }
};

command_process.OutputDataReceived += StandardOutputDataHandler;
standard_output = new StringBuilder();

command_process.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorOutputDataHandler;
error_output = new StringBuilder();

command_output = new StringBuilder();

command_process.Start();

command_process.BeginOutputReadLine();
command_process.BeginErrorReadLine();

command_process.WaitForExit();
```

...

```
private void StandardOutputDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    Console.WriteLine("StandardOutputDataHandler");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data)) return;
    Console.WriteLine("After null StandardOutputDataHandler");

    lock (command_output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StandardOutputDataHandler output: {0}", outLine.Data);
        standard_output.Append(Environment.NewLine + "  " + outLine.Data);
        command_output.Append(Environment.NewLine + "  " + outLine.Data);
        has_standard_output = true;
        ParseOutput();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("End StandardOutputDataHandler");
}

private void ErrorOutputDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ErrorOutputDataHandler");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data)) return;
    Console.WriteLine("After null ErrorOutputDataHandler");

    lock (command_output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ErrorOutputDataHandler output: {0}", outLine.Data);
        error_output.Append(Environment.NewLine + "  " + outLine.Data);
        command_output.Append(Environment.NewLine + "  " + outLine.Data);
        has_error_output = true;
        ParseOutput();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("End ErrorOutputDataHandler");
}
```

This happens for any interactive commands such as (replace escapedArgs with any of the following) :

```
mysql -u root -p
ftp x.x.x.x
```

When it starts running, it ouputs the console:

```
Enter password:
```

in the case of the mysql command which seems to me it sent the output before the Process has attached the output buffer, not sure if that's the best interpretation. And it enters the StandardOutputDataHandler or ErrorOutputDataHandler only after a few seconds, with empty data and then the Process closes as well.

Not sure how to work around the issue or what the explanation for how it happens is.

Thanks